# Глобальные переменные js

Tags: javascript

Есть примерно такой код (привожу урезанную версию)

```
var gitem, nitem, items;

function load_items() {
    $.post('script.php', {'type': 'items'}).done(function(arr){
        items = JSON.parse(arr);
        $.each(items, function(i, item){
            // обработка
        });
    });
}
load_items();

function switch_to_new() {
    $.post('script2.php', {'type': 'new'}).done(function(arr){
        var jp = JSON.parse(arr);
        $.each(jp, function(i, comment){
            $.each(items, function(i, item){
                if (item.id != comment.id){return}
                gitem = item;
                return false;
            });
            $('#main').append(`
                <span class="article" rate=${gitem.starsavg} comms=${gitem.cnt}>
            `);
            // здесь ошибка
        });
    });
}
```

На локальном сервере (Open Server) все работает отлично, но после выгрузки на хостинг в строке `<span class="article" rate=${gitem.starsavg}  comms=${gitem.cnt}>` появляется ошибка
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'starsavg' of undefined*

Comment: очевидно не выполнилась строка `gitem = item;` Проверь данные с которыми ты работаешь

Comment: Проверил, данные в норме. Насколько я понял, скрипт выполняется до этой строки `$.each(jp, function(i, comment){` и вылетает.

Comment: нет. Добавь в вопрос пример данным с которыми работаешь

Comment: непонятно когда вызывается функция _switch_to_new_

Comment: она обрабатывает событие onclick одного из div, тут я это просто не указал

Comment: важно время когда это происходит, два варианта - первый, приходят плохие данные, что gitem не заполняется, второй - items - пустой, потому что в момент вызова еще не установилось значение. Что именно причина - по текущему куску кода нельзя сказать